# best approach for tableview with rows expand and collapse option

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, customization

I have view which contains tableview and searchbar. When i begin searching it should search the tableview. Below is the sample data of tableview in attached  image:[image]

STUDENT 1, STUDENT 2 are different sections in the table

Suppose i search for "S" then result should be as shown below where matched rows should be visible and unmatched rows - should be hidden and a button "Show Remaining" should be visible. When i click on "Show Remaining" button it should show remaining rows of the same section :

[image]

how do i achieve this and if possible please provide the example for above scenario.

Comment: A few questions to better understand your demands. 1. What happens with STUDENT sections, where none of rows matches the search? 2. Does button "Show remaining" affect only one section each or is it on button for all sections?

Comment: @ Sergii Martynenko Jr - there is "Show Remaining" button for each section. If there is no match in a section that section is hidden or removed.

Comment: Would be nice, if you provide us with feedback, did any of answers help you?

Comment: @ Sergii Martynenko J,Ramkrishna Sharma,Hasya - thanks a lot guys for ur prompt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created the code for your requirement please find the below url for download the code and review it.

Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/22ijwgxybn98wyj/ExpandCollapse.zip?dl=0

> Environment : Xcode 8 and Objective-C

**Highlight of the code which I had done it.**

I had created NSObject of student based on your structure, create two(StudentListCell and ShowMoreCell) `UITableViewCell` for display the record of student and "Show Remaining button" record.

Also I have taken two(arrStudentInfo, arrSearchInfo) `NSMutablebleArray` for keeping the search records and original records.

After that I initilize the NSObject of student in `ViewController.m`. Please find the below code.

```
- (void)setupData {

    self.arrStudentInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrSearchInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    StudentInfo *student_1 = [[StudentInfo alloc] init];
    student_1.name = @"Sia S";
    student_1.style = @"S";
    student_1.trend = @"S";
    student_1.age = @"60";
    student_1.locale = @"Node";
    student_1.street = @"BR";
    student_1.city = @"JP";
    student_1.country = @"US";
    student_1.isOpen = YES;
    student_1.isShowMore = NO;
    [self.arrStudentInfo addObject:student_1];

    StudentInfo *student_2 = [[StudentInfo alloc] init];
    student_2.name = @"Nitin";
    student_2.style = @"N";
    student_2.trend = @"N";
    student_2.age = @"40";
    student_2.locale = @"Node";
    student_2.street = @"BR";
    student_2.city = @"SP";
    student_2.country = @"US";
    student_2.isOpen = YES;
    student_2.isShowMore = NO;
    [self.arrStudentInfo addObject:student_2];
}
```

I had created the method which return the currently active which means search record or original record of array.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getCurrentArray {

    if(self.isSearch)
        return self.arrSearchInfo;
    else
        return self.arrStudentInfo;
}
```

Load the data based on scenario,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    StudentInfo *studentInfo = [self getCurrentArray][indexPath.section];

    if(indexPath.row == SHOW_MORE_INDEX && studentInfo.isShowMore == NO) {

        static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"ShowMoreCell";
        ShowMoreCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
        cell.btnShowMore.tag = indexPath.section;
        [cell.btnShowMore addTarget:self action:@selector(clickONShowMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell;
    }

    else {

        static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"StudentListCell";

        StudentListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
        [cell setupCell:studentInfo indexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

For searching the student name,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.isSearch = YES;

    NSPredicate *predicateStudent = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.name CONTAINS[cd] '%@'",searchBar.text]];
    NSArray *arrGetSearch = [self.arrStudentInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateStudent];

    if(self.arrSearchInfo.count)
        [self.arrSearchInfo removeAllObjects];

    [self.arrSearchInfo addObjectsFromArray:arrGetSearch];
    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

And again load the original record if user click on "X" button on `UISearchbar`.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil) {

        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        self.isSearch = NO;
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Actually, not the best approach in some senses. For example, you've placed property "isShowMore" into model class Student, which is bad practice. "Show all" option has nothing to do with Model, which Student class is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I have taken the isShowMore flag in model to identify each record whether it allows to show more or not. Please let me know whether I have to place it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples available for expand and collapse table.

You can refer below example

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

By setting up dynamically in plist file. you can maintain expandable and collapsable tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellNormal" {
        if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = primaryTitle as? String
        }

        if let secondaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = secondaryTitle as? String
        }
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
        cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellSwitch" {
        cell.lblSwitchLabel.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String

        let value = currentCellDescriptor["value"] as? String
        cell.swMaritalStatus.on = (value == "true") ? true : false
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellValuePicker" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellSlider" {
        let value = currentCellDescriptor["value"] as! String
        cell.slExperienceLevel.value = (value as NSString).floatValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any general "best approach" for collapsing/expanding behaviour in UITableView. I suspect that is the reason why there's no provided by Apple. Instead, they gave us enough instruments to implement it the way we wish.

In your particular case I have next vision.
I don't know, and don't need to know, how exactly do you work with model side of your task and the following code serves only this answer's purpose, which is - to provide you with collapsing behaviour you seek.

I would suggest to implement your desired behaviour in such a manner. In ViewController, in which you control both search bar and table view add fields

```
@property NSArray* filteredStudents;
@property NSMutableIndexSet* expandedStudents;
```

Those properties would be nil (or empty instances) while no search is taking place. Once search starts (first symbols entered or "Search" button tapped - whatever you like most) - instantiate them.

`filteredStudents` - array that holds reference to those students, that satisfy your search criteria. It is updated every time search executed. Each time you update it - do [tableView reloadData].

`expandedStudents` - index set that tells you in which sections have user pressed "Show all". Don't forget - it holds only section numbers. So, when `filteredStudents` array changes, you have to update it manually. For example, when you entered "S" - you have two students shown. You press Show All on the second student. `expandStudents` now has number `1` in it. Than you enter "Se", and only second student remains. You have to, in that case, replace `1` in `expandedStudents` with `0`, 'cause second student's section becomes first.

Another property

```
 @property BOOL searchMode;
```

This property should be YES whenever filtered results display takes place. NO - otherwise.

Next, modify UITableViewDataSource and Delegate methods like this

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if(searchMode) {
       return self.filteredStudents.count;
    }
    else {
       //Your current behaviour here
    }
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(searchMode) {
       if([self.expandedStudents containsIndex:section]) { // Button "Show all" was already tapped for this student
          return /* Number of all fields you need to show for student. Just like you do now. It is for expanded section */
       }
       else {
           return /* Number of fields that satisfy search criteria for student self.filteredStudents[section] */
       }
    }
    else {
       //Your current behaviour here
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(searchMode) {
        if(![self.expandedStudents containsIndex:section] && /* indexPath corresponds to place, where "Show All" should be */) {
           //Create "Show All" cell
        }
        else {
          //Create cell that contains info from filtered student fields
        }
    }
    else {
       //Your current behaviour here
    }
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
   if(searchMode && ![self.expandedStudents containsIndex:section] && /* indexPath corresponds to place, where "Show All" should be */) {
      //"Show All" button pressed
      [self.expandedStudents addIndex:indexPath.section];

      [tableView beginUpdates];
      /* For each row, that wasn't presented in collapsed student perform insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method */
      [tableView endUpdates];
   }
   else {
      //Your current behaviour
   }
}
```